# Will the CreateTable action (with tags supplied) in AWS DynamoDB fail if an SCP is applied that restricts tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

For example; let's say I have account with an SCP applied which denies all tagging and untagging in DynamoDB in that account.

Will all roles in that account be prevented from creating tables in DynamoDB that have tags?

For reference I am talking about the CreateTable action here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running an experiment on AWS, I found that the table creation was denied if tags were provided but allowed if tags were not provided.

So the answer is **yes**, all roles in that account will be prevented from creating tables with tags in DynamoDB, unless the role is given an exemption in the SCP.